# Delphi 11.1 - Failure in generating binary in Release mode - Debug mode works

Tags: delphi, service, compiler-errors, delphi-11-alexandria

I have a problem with one of my projects. It's a Windows service.

When I compile the code in Debug configuration, everything works.
But when I try compiling in Release configuration, I get the following message:

> [dcc64 Fataler Fehler] pHubService.dpr(6): E2213 Falsches gepacktes Unit-Format: c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Win64\release\vcl.dcp.Vcl.SvcMgr - Erwartete Version: 35.0, Windows Unicode(x64) Gefundene Version: 84.53, Unk(CIL)

English:

> [dcc64 Fatal Error] pHubService.dpr(6): E2213 Bad packaged unit format: c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Win64\release\vcl.dcp.Vcl.SvcMgr - Expected version : 35.0, Windows Unicode(x64) Version Found: 84.53, Unk(CIL)

The system is a new installed system, with a nearly fresh Delphi installation. I don't know what to do. Has anyone had this problem before? I think it must be something in the Configuration, but I can't find any mistakes.

Comment: "*with a **nearly fresh** Delphi installation*" - mearning what, exactly? Why is it only "nearly" fresh and not entirely fresh? Did you copy files from another installation, or something?

Comment: [E2213 Bad packaged unit format %s.%s (Delphi)](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2213_Bad_packaged_unit_format_%25s.%25s_(Delphi))

Comment: No, I have some Packages installed from get-it. Nothing else. The Project is from A earlier installation of Delphi 10.4 but does not work in that as well. Same failure message.

Comment: I found that Link too and the Compiler is really clear at that Point. But I have no influence on that file.